# Prove an ideal is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Question
>
> Prove the ideal $\mathrm I=\{f \in \mathrm R| f(2)=0 \}$ of $\mathrm R=\{f(x) | f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ is continue} is maximal.
>
> **DO NOT use the $1$st isomorphism theorem.**
>
> ---

I tried.

> > (1) $\mathrm I \neq \mathrm R$
> >
> > (2) Suppose that if  "$\mathrm I \subseteq \mathrm J \subseteq \mathrm R$ where $J$ is ideal of $\mathrm R$".
> >
> > For all  $f(x) \in \mathrm I$,  $f(x) \in \mathrm J=\{ j(x)h(x)$ | $ h(x) \in \mathrm R\}$
> >
> > Since $f(2)=0$, $f(x)=j(x)h(x)$ for some $h(x) \in \mathrm R$. (ie. $j(2)h(2)=0$)
> >
> > If $j(2)=0$, then $j(x) \in \mathrm I$. so $\mathrm I = \mathrm J $.
> >
> > And we show that if $\mathrm I \neq \mathrm J$, then $\mathrm J = \mathrm R $.
> >
> > If $f(2)=j(2)h(2)=0$ and $j(2) \neq 0$ then, there exist $g(x) \in \mathrm J$
> >      s.t $g(2) \neq 0$.
> >
> > moreover there exist $g(x) \in J$ s.t $g(2)=1$. And $g(x)$ is continues.
> >
> > So we also take $g(x)=1$.
> >
> > $g(x)=1 \in \mathrm J$. ( ie. $\mathrm J$ contains unit.)
> >
> > threrfore $\mathrm J=\mathrm R$. ($\mathrm I \neq \mathrm R$)
> >
> > we conclude $\mathrm I$ is maximal ideal of $\mathrm R$.

is it all right? please fix it or hint. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by $J=\{j(x)h(x)\mid h(x)\in R\}$? What's $j(x)$? You seem to believe that ideals are principal, which is false in general.

Comment: i fix it. $\mathrm J$ is maximal ideal.and i prove another way. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x-2)^2\in I$. If there is $g(x) \in J$ such that $g(2)\neq 0$ then

$$(x-2)^2+(g(x))^2 \in J$$ and this function has no zeros so is invertible.

Comment: wow! thank you!!!!!! :D

Comment: My pleasure....